# Link preload with axios

Tags: axios, xmlhttprequest, preload

Can I use `<link href="https://something/123" rel="preload" as="fetch">` with `axios`? Preload headers must be equal to axios headers.

> A preload for `https://something/123` is found, but is not used
> because the request headers do not match.

Preload sets `sec-fetch-mode: no-cors`, and axios sets `sec-fetch-mode: cors`. I found out [here](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/axios-vs-fetch-no-cors-mode), that I can't change `fetch-mode` in axios

> It's important to note is that mode, credentials, and crossdomain
> aren't supported for configuring Axios.

So I decided to set `crossOrigin="anonymous"` and now preload uses `sec-fetch-mode: cors` but also adds `origin` header . `origin` header can't be added in axios.